# Open (chrome) devtools in horizontal mode

Tags: google-chrome

My current version (39.0.2171.95) opens the devTools in a vertical mode by default - can you change it somehow?

Comment: I'd say just close it in that layout mode and it should open up this way the next time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a small button for this in the top right corner.

[image]

Comment: The OP is asking about the *default behavior*

Comment: @haim770 yes, seems like after you switched the devTools position, this dock mode becomes a default setting for all tabs.

Comment: I thought so too, checked newly opened windows in Incognito mode and it didn't save. On regular windows, it does use recent docking mode.

Comment: Some times after "Undock into separate window" you need to do a long click on mentioned icon, then choose docked console orientation you need from popup.

Answer (score 9):

In newest updates of Chrome and Opera there is shortcut "ctrl + shift + D" to make inspector horizontal

Comment: Also in Brave browser.

Comment: Or cmd + shift + d on Mac